# How to show an objects kinetic energy per unit of surface area is proportional to $m^{2/3}$ at terminal velocity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, mathematical-physics

A falling spherical object of mass $m$ with surface area $S$ and constant density
$p$ experiences an atmospheric drag proportional to $Sv^2$, where $v$ is the velocity of the object.

How do you show that, when the object reaches its terminal velocity, the kinetic energy per unit of its surface area is proportional to
$m^{2/3}$.

The kinetic energy is defined as the mass of the object multiplied by its velocity squared and the terminal velocity is reached when the falling object stops accelerating due to the air drag.

Comment: Why is it falling? What is the terminal velocity exactly?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: many of us want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: Its the terminal speed $V_t= \sqrt{\frac{2*m*g}{\rho*A*C_d }}$

Comment: And what's the definition of terminal speed?

Comment: Okay so if were to compare objects of the same form and specific mass and the same velocity then m is proportional to its length^3 so length is proportional to m^1/3 surface is proportional to length^2 so also to (m^1/3)² = m^2/3 kinetic energy is proportional to m kinetic energy per unit of its surface area = kinetic energy/ surface; this is proportional to m/(m^2/3) = m*(m^3/2)=m^5/2 but this doesn't make sense so I just need help with this

Comment: And why is the object falling? I.e. what's the potential? Is it propotional to $r^{-1}$? Or $r$? Or something else?

Comment: The potential causing it to fall is from gravity and it should be proportional to $r^-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following relationships can be established for the spherical object,

$$mg= Sv^2$$
$$S=4\pi r^2$$
$$m=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 p$$

where $r$ is the radius of the sphere and the first equation equalizes the gravitational force with the drag.

So, the kinetic energy per unit of surface area is

$$\frac{mv^2}{S}=\frac{m^2g}{S^2}=\frac{m^2g}{16\pi^2 r^4}=\frac{m^2g}{16\pi^2 \left(\frac{3m}{4\pi p} \right)^{4/3 }}$$
$$=\frac{m^{\frac{2}{3}}g}{\left(\frac{36\pi}{p^2} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

which is proportional to $m^{2/3}$.